# Dropdownlist On Second Choose First Selected wont Display:none;

Tags: javascript

JS

```
function getData(dropdown) {
    var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    if (value == 'emlak'){
    document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "block";
    }
    if(value == 'vasita'){
    document.getElementById("vasita").style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<select name="kategori" onChange="getData(this);">
     <option value="hat" onClick="">Hat</option>
     <option value="emlak">Shirt</option>
     <option value="vasita">Pants</option>
</select>
<select id="emlak" name="currentList" onChange=";" style="display:none;">
     <option value="hat">Hat</option>
     <option value="emlak">Shirt</option>
     <option value="pants">Pants</option>
</select>
<select id="vasita" name="currentList" onChange="" style="display:none;">
     <option value="hat">Otomobil</option>
     <option value="emlak">Shirt</option>
     <option value="pants">Pants</option>
</select>
```

> When I Choose a Option second time first selected option wont display:none; it should show just one select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not setting it to none. That would be the reason why.

```
function getData(dropdown) {
    var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    if (value == 'emlak'){
    document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "block";  //where is the none for the other element?
    }
    if(value == 'vasita'){
    document.getElementById("vasita").style.display = "block"; //where is the none for the other element?
    }
}
```

Basic idea:

```
function getData(dropdown) {
    var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    var isEmlak = (value == 'emlak');
    document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = isEmlak ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("vasita").style.display = !isEmlak ? "block" : "none";
}
```

Comment: but when i set none it dont show anything it should display and when choose second option first selected should set to display:none; how can it be?

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about, Did you miss the block that actually has the solution, not the one that I pointed out your error? It works http://jsfiddle.net/XC82v/ and requires a lot less copy paste than the selected answer.

Comment: i made it more flexible for multi tasks i hope it will be usefull for other people

`function getData(dropdown) { 
  var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
  if (value == 'emlak'){
    document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "block";
  } else if(value != 'emlak'){
   document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "none";
  }if(value == 'vasita'){
    document.getElementById("vasita").style.display = "block";  
  }else if(value != 'vasita'){
   document.getElementById("vasita").style.display = "none";
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is refernced [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ArUYOXi/1/edit)

```
function getData(dropdown) { 
  var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
  if (value == 'emlak'){
    document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("vasita").style.display = "none"; 
  }
  if(value == 'vasita'){
    document.getElementById("vasita").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "none";  
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the script like the below:

```
function getData(dropdown) {
    var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    if (value == 'emlak'){
        document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("vasita").style.display = "none";
    }

    if(value == 'vasita'){
        document.getElementById("vasita").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "none";
    }

    if(value == 'hat'){
        document.getElementById("vasita").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```